# JQuery Mobile select in listview, binding with KnockoutJs

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, select, knockout.js

I have an issue when I'm trying to use a select in a JQM listview.

I have a listview to list a couple of computers and in every listitem the user are able to make some changes to the computers via dropdownlists.

Here is the result: 
[image: JQM issue]

I'm using knockoutjs to bind viewModels to the view.

Here is my listview:

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="content">
    <ul id="editComputerList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    PC
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    Lokasjon
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    OS
                </div>
                <div class="column-last">
                    Språk
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- ko foreach: Computers -->
        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column" data-bind="text: Name">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <select data-bind="value: Location, options: $root.Locations, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Value'">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <select data-bind="value: OsParameter, options: $root.OsParameters, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Value'">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="column-last">
                    <select data-bind="value: Language, options: $root.Languages, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Value'">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And here am I binding the model to the view:

```js
var viewModel = new pageViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("page1"));
$("#editComputerList", "#page1").listview("refresh");
$('#editComputerList select').selectmenu();
$('#editComputerList select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

​

Code can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/dankli/7hJ5d/

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong or is it a bug in JQM?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by setting data-role="none" on the select.

```
<select data-role="none" ...></select>
```

But I don't know if that is the way to go.